# Modifying the contents of EnumDropDownListFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using an enum to populate a dropdown list using Html.EnumDropDownListFor, the problem is by convention the enum is all capped for what I'm working on, so when it goes to populate the drop down everything is all capped. I looked to see if there was a way to do a toTitleCase or even toLower, something that would look a little less ridiculous, but I've been unable to get it to work (toString just writes the actual html instead, which makes sense).

Is there anyway to do this without writing out the html for a dropdown list? Or am I going to just need to suck it up and write everything out by hand? Just to clarify exactly what I want done, I would prefer to be able to TitleCase everything.

Comment: I think that this is not possible however you could give your select an html class, then use an easy javascript code to change the content to TitleCase everything.

Comment: You can always add a `[Display(Name = "xxx")]` to each enum value where `xxx` is the value in TitleCase (and can include spaces). Otherwise just use a view model with its own enum where the values are in TitleCase

Comment: I hadn't thought about Display, that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem

```
[Display(Name="White")]
WHITE,
[Display(Name = "Black")]
BLACK,
[Display(Name = "Green")]
GREEN,
[Display(Name = "Yellow")]
YELLOW,
[Display(Name = "Specialty")]
SPECIALTY,
[Display(Name = "Oolong")]
OOLONG,
[Display(Name = "Rooibos")]
ROOIBOS,
[Display(Name = "Pu-erh")]
PUERH,
[Display(Name = "Herbal")]
HERBAL
```